# GPA regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to make a GPA validation regex in Perl, and I seem to have something wrong with my logic. You should be able to end a number 0-3 followed by a . with 1 more digit in the range of 0-9. or if the first digit is a 4 it must be followed with a .0 Here's my code:

```
$get_gpa_input =~ m/[0-3]\.\d[0-9]|[4].[0]/
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[0-9]`. You've also got some extra brackets and you should escape the decimal in '4.0'.

```
$get_gpa_input =~ m/[0-3]\.\d|4\.0/
```

Comment: `\d` matches way more than just `[0-9]` unless `/a` is in effect.

Comment: Correct, although more than likely not a concern here.

Comment: What does `  \  ` after the 4 and before the .0 mean?

Comment: It escapes the . so it is treated as a literal character to match, not its special regex meaning.

Answer (score 3):

```
m/(?: [0-3] [.] [0-9] ) | 4[.]0 /x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing validation, you don't want to search within a string but rather to force the entire string to match your regex; you do this by adding anchors to the beginning and ending:

```
/\A (?: [0-3]\.[0-9] | 4\.0 ) \z/x
```

`\A` matches only before the first character of the string, `\z` matches only after the last character of the string.

Avoid using `\d` in most code since it can match any number of Unicode "digits" that aren't 0 through 9 (though in newer perls, the /a flag reverts it to its old ASCII meaning).

Answer (score 0):

You have `\d[0-9]` which would require *two* digits following 0-3.  You also don't escape the decimal in the 4 alternate, which may make a difference.

```
[0-3]\.\d|4\.0
```